# How do I get these permissions working right so Apache can work with the files?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I am having a go at setting up my own Apache and can't seem to get my head around the permissions.

Lets say I grab a file from somewhere off the web and it has permission of 600.

I then upload this file via ftp to a user directory, which is also an apache virtual site, and so this file retains this permission of 600. This means that the user can read this file, but Apache can't: it will be forbidden.

What is the most simple solution so that apache can read + write whatever files end up in the users directory? Can apache be granted some sort of root power over files in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ACL to give apache the permissions to the whole subtree or use ACL for everything (ftp users and apache) :). I would use ACL for everything as I think it is easier and better to keep everything working in the same direction.

[ACL guide on CentOS](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-acls-setting.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html).

If you have a directory inside the user home directory called 'public_html'

```
chgrp apache /home/username/public_html
chmod 750 /home/username/public_html
chmod g+s /home/username/public_html
```

then this will mean new files created in that directory will be automatically readable by the apache group.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: chmod to 660 will allow the Group apache and the mentioned user is in to write to the files - you might have to add the ftp user to the apache Group.

Long recommeneded answer: http://www.csgnetwork.com/csgchmodcalc.html - if your ftpd supports it, you can set chmod permissions via ftp.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I'd need to chmod every time I upload the files? I know how I can manually chmod the files to change their permissions, but I'm looking for a way that means apache will be considered to have the same permission as the user.

Comment: of course you can change the ftpds umask or upload username - or apaches.

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at using "inotifywait". This lets you watch for changes in a directory and files. this website http://hardc0l2e.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/folder-monitoring-script-using-inotifywait/  contains a script that simply outputs the files changed. You could update it to do whatever you want, for example to chmod the files to your wishes!